# Neo4j embedded database ignores transaction log limits

Tags: java, neo4j

Using Neo4j 3.0.4, the embedded database totally ignores dbms.tx_log.rotation.retention_policy. There is no difference whether loading it from a configuration file with

```
new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder(STORE_FOLDER).loadPropertiesFromURL(CONFIG_FILE).newGraphDatabase();
```

or setting it with

```
new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder(STORE_FOLDER).SetConfig(GraphDatabaseSettings.keep_logical_logs, DBMS_TX_LOG_ROTATION_RETENTION_POLICY).newGraphDatabase();
```

It doesn't change whether it is limited in size (`100M size`) or in number (`3 files`). It happily writes transaction logs until the hard disk is full.

However `GraphDatabaseSettings.logical_log_rotation_threshold` works just fine.

Did I miss something while configuring? Did I not understand the purpose of the retention policy, or is this a bug in Neo4j 3.0.4?

Answer (score 0):

Transaction logs are pruned or at least checked for possible be pruned every checkpoint. A checkpoint may happen many minutes apart (dictated by time and tx-count settings). In between those checkpoints there's no guarantee about transaction log size.